# Shared DLL between application and Shared session

Tags: asp.net

I have a web site with a bunch of DLL in the bin directory. I have to use a newer version pf AjaxControlToolkit and I can't replace the old one.

So I create a virtual directory in the web site. I copy the new AjaxControlToolkit and the others DLL. But when I try to get the session variable (accessed normaly by the website DLL) I got nothing. It's correct because I'm isolated in a new application. But if I delete the virtual directory application, I will use the website bin, and the older AjaxControlToolkit too. Damned!

My need: Use a newer version of AjaxControlToolkit and get the same session (in a InProc mode) of the Web site.

At last, I can send information via URL and use a querystring fonction....But...

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the session then. Therefore, you'll need to use a querystring parameter as you stated, or better yet, do a POST or save to a cookie instead (encrypt if necessary). Are you sure you can't update your AjaxControlToolkit?